# jQuery: looping array to compile url get variables and values

Tags: arrays, jquery, get, each

I have an array in jQuery, and I'm using `$.each()` to loop through the array. I'm trying to find a way to compile a URL link using the values in the array

```
var selectArr = ["numbers123", "more_array_values", "etc", "more"];
            $.each(selectArr,function(k,v){
                k++;
                alert('fid'+k+'='+v);
            });
```

This works,

But I would like to somehow get it so it'll be like

`var url = fid1=numbers123&fid2=more_array_values&fid3=etc` ...

This way, I can use `url` and append it to a `<a href=''>`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var selectArr = ["numbers123", "more_array_values", "etc", "more"];
var parts = [];
$.each(selectArr,function(k,v){
    parts.push('fid'+(k+1)+'='+v)
});
var url = parts.join('&');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eHcmd/1/)

You can clean up the answer by using the [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function as Felix said

I would recommend using that method over mine.

Comment: @FelixKling it was done after my answer was accepted and he said your was not working. I corrected the mistake in your answer and put remarks saying it was yours. Sorry for it and I've removed it

Comment: Thanks for informing me to use @FelixKling, but I'd accept your answer because it gave me no trouble at the moment, and his reputation is higher than yours! I'll give you some slack :)

Answer (score 3):

With some creative application of [`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) and the array method `.join`:

```
var url = $.map(selectArr, function(v,k) {
    // encodeURIComponent makes the value "URL safe"
    return 'fid' + (k + 1) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(v);   
}).join('&');
```

Comment: for some reason the equal sign doesn't fall into the right place

Comment: Oh, it's because in `$.map` the arguments are in reverse order (`v, k`, not `k, v`). Fixed.

Comment: Thank you! I gave Arun P Johny some slack because you have great reputation!! I'll use your code :) thanks for helping!